# Unable to get Value data from get-properties

Tags: powershell

I'm using an xml variable and I need to get property data of all properties and values recursively and assign them to an object.

So for example,

```
$xml.object1 #has sub properties and is a System.Xml.XmlElement

$xml.object2 #has sub properties and is a System.Xml.XmlElement

$xml.object3 #is a string

$xml.object4 #is a string.
```

I want to get each of the sub properties in object1 and object2 which also may contain System.Xml.XmlElement objects to which I would want to recurse and get the string values in that and so on.

My issue isn't getting the object and values from the parent object but more the child System.Xml.XmlElement objects and their data. A System.Xml.XmlElement can have several other System.Xml.XmlElements and those can have children that have children and so on.
i.e.

```
$xml.object1.object11.object111.object1111
$xml.object1.object12.1object122
$xml.object1.object12.1object121.object1211
```

etc

After trying Do/Until scripts `until ($me = massive headache)`, I started playing around with `get-properties`. The problem I'm facing with get-properties is that I can't seem to use the output to get the values of the properties.

I tried the following returning no results.

```
get-properties -object $xml -pathname object1 | select -first 1 | foreach-object {
#attempt1
$p = $xml.$_
$p

#attempt2
$string = $_ | out-string
$xml.$string

}

get-properties -object $xml | select -first 1 | foreach-object {

#attempt3
$split = $_ -split ('$_.') | select -last 1 | out-string
$xml.$split

#attempt4
[string]$string = $_
$split = $string -split ('$_.') | select -last 1
$xml.$split

#attempt5
$string = $_ | out-string
$split = $string -split ('$_.') | select -last 1
$xml.$split
}
```

Because the basetype for the object is a system.object, I'm not sure how to convert it into a string to use in order to get the value of the property.

I hope my question is clear and I appreciate any assistance.

Here is some sample XML from the document I'm working with which is generated by gpresult but it's part of a much larger project in general:

```
            <OneX xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/OneX/v1">
              <cacheUserData>true</cacheUserData>
              <heldPeriod>1</heldPeriod>
              <authPeriod>18</authPeriod>
              <startPeriod>5</startPeriod>
              <maxStart>3</maxStart>
              <maxAuthFailures>1</maxAuthFailures>
              <authMode>machineOrUser</authMode>
              <singleSignOn>
                <type>postLogon</type>
                <maxDelay>10</maxDelay>
                <allowAdditionalDialogs>false</allowAdditionalDialogs>
                <userBasedVirtualLan>false</userBasedVirtualLan>
              </singleSignOn>
              <EAPConfig>
                <EapHostConfig xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig">
                  <EapMethod>
                    <Type xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">25</Type>
                    <VendorId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</VendorId>
                    <VendorType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</VendorType>
                    <AuthorId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</AuthorId>
                  </EapMethod>
                  <Config xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig">
                    <Eap xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1">
                      <Type>25</Type>
                      <EapType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV1">
                        <ServerValidation>
                          <DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>false</DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>
                          <ServerNames>
                          </ServerNames>
                        </ServerValidation>
                        <FastReconnect>true</FastReconnect>
                        <InnerEapOptional>false</InnerEapOptional>
                        <Eap xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1">
                          <Type>26</Type>
                          <EapType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsChapV2ConnectionPropertiesV1">
                            <UseWinLogonCredentials>true</UseWinLogonCredentials>
                          </EapType>
                        </Eap>
                        <EnableQuarantineChecks>false</EnableQuarantineChecks>
                        <RequireCryptoBinding>false</RequireCryptoBinding>
                        <PeapExtensions>
                          <PerformServerValidation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2">true</PerformServerValidation>
                          <AcceptServerName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2">false</AcceptServerName>
                        </PeapExtensions>
                      </EapType>
                    </Eap>
                  </Config>
                </EapHostConfig>
              </EAPConfig>
            </OneX>
```

To be clearer. This example is a child of many parent properties. I want to look at this as if each property and sub property were root properties. nothing is nested. I also want to filter out the xmlns urls and if the property name is type, it uses "$xml.localname Type" for the property name. it is a lot.

## The Solution

I used the TheMadTechnician's script and modified it a little to get what I needed after doing a little reverse engineering.

Here's ultimately what I came up with using the script he provided:

```
select-xml -xml $onex -XPath '//*'|?{$_.node.'#text'}|%{
    $ThisNode = $_.Node
    $PathArr = do{
        $ThisNode.Name
        $ThisNode = $ThisNode.psbase.parentnode
    }until(!$ThisNode.psbase.parentnode)
    [array]::Reverse($PathArr)
    $PathString = $PathArr -join '.'
    if ($pathstring -like "*.OneX*")
    {
        $selectlast1 = $pathstring -split ('OneX.') | select -Last 1
        if ($selectlast1 -like "*type")
        {
            [string]$n = ($selectlast1.split('.') | select -Last 2) -join (' ')
        }
        else
        {
            [string]$n = $selectlast1.split('.') | select -Last 1
        }
        
        [string]$v = $_.node.'#Text'
        $onexobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $n -Value $v 
        
    }
}
```

Thank you to everyone who posted suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide example XML, and what your intended end result is? I can't help but wonder if `Select-Xml` is the cmdlet you're looking for, but without knowing what exactly you're trying to accomplish it's hard to say.

Comment: select-xml won't work. I need to get the names of the properties without being able to define them explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still believe that `Select-Xml` is the correct cmdlet for you. You don't need to specify property names, you just need to use the proper XPath filter. For example, the XPath '//*' will return every node. If you wanted to build out the path to that node you would have to crawl up the hierarchy and build it, but that's not too difficult. For the sample XML that you provided if you run this:

```
select-xml -xml $xml -XPath '//*'|?{$_.node.'#text'}|%{
    $ThisNode = $_.Node
    $PathArr = do{
        $ThisNode.Name
        $ThisNode = $ThisNode.psbase.parentnode
    }until(!$ThisNode.psbase.parentnode)
    [array]::Reverse($PathArr)
    $PathString = $PathArr -join '.'
    "`$xml.{0} = {1}" -f $PathString, $_.node.'#Text'
}
```

It would output a list of all nodes that have a string like this:

```
$xml.OneX.cacheUserData = true
$xml.OneX.heldPeriod = 1
$xml.OneX.authPeriod = 18
$xml.OneX.startPeriod = 5
$xml.OneX.maxStart = 3
$xml.OneX.maxAuthFailures = 1
$xml.OneX.authMode = machineOrUser
$xml.OneX.singleSignOn.type = postLogon
$xml.OneX.singleSignOn.maxDelay = 10
$xml.OneX.singleSignOn.allowAdditionalDialogs = false
$xml.OneX.singleSignOn.userBasedVirtualLan = false
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.EapMethod.Type = 25
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.EapMethod.VendorId = 0
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.EapMethod.VendorType = 0
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.EapMethod.AuthorId = 0
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.Type = 25
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.EapType.ServerValidation.DisableUserPromptForServerValidation = false
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.EapType.FastReconnect = true
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.EapType.InnerEapOptional = false
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.EapType.Eap.Type = 26
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.EapType.Eap.EapType.UseWinLogonCredentials = true
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.EapType.EnableQuarantineChecks = false
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.EapType.RequireCryptoBinding = false
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.EapType.PeapExtensions.PerformServerValidation = true
$xml.OneX.EAPConfig.EapHostConfig.Config.Eap.EapType.PeapExtensions.AcceptServerName = false
```

Since you weren't really specific about what you wanted to get for output I went with the first example you gave as a format. If you don't need the full path to the value you could do something as simple as:

```
select-xml -xml $xml -XPath '//*'|?{$_.node.'#text'}|%{$_.node.name + ' = ' + $_.node.'#Text'}
```

which would output:

```
cacheUserData = true
heldPeriod = 1
authPeriod = 18
startPeriod = 5
maxStart = 3
maxAuthFailures = 1
authMode = machineOrUser
type = postLogon
maxDelay = 10
allowAdditionalDialogs = false
userBasedVirtualLan = false
Type = 25
VendorId = 0
VendorType = 0
AuthorId = 0
Type = 25
DisableUserPromptForServerValidation = false
FastReconnect = true
InnerEapOptional = false
Type = 26
UseWinLogonCredentials = true
EnableQuarantineChecks = false
RequireCryptoBinding = false
PerformServerValidation = true
AcceptServerName = false
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this. for each property I'm creating 2 variables a name and value and adding them to a pscustomobject. I'm going to do some editing to make the 'Type' property names more specific, but I really like what you did here and I'm gonna play around with it to see if I can bend it to my will so to speak. I really didn't think I could do it with select-xml, but you sir have proved me wrong. I was completely wrong so I'm sorry for dismissing your suggestion so quickly. This is perfect though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow programmer.
I think this recursive function could work in your favor:

```
function Convert-XmlElementToList {
    param (
        [System.Xml.XmlElement]$xmlElement
    )

    $result = @()

    # Recursively process child elements
    foreach ($childNode in $xmlElement.ChildNodes) {
        if ($childNode -is [System.Xml.XmlElement]) {
            $result += Convert-XmlElementToList -xmlElement $childNode
        }
    }

    # Convert the current element to a PSObject
    $elementProperties = @{
        'Name' = $xmlElement.Name
        'InnerText' = $xmlElement.InnerText
        'Attributes' = @{}
    }

    foreach ($attribute in $xmlElement.Attributes) {
        $elementProperties['Attributes'][$attribute.Name] = $attribute.Value
    }

    $psObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $elementProperties
    $result += $psObject

    return $result
}
```

This is how u could use it:

```
$xml = @"
<root>
    <parent>
        <child1 attribute1="value1">text1</child1>
        <child2 attribute2="value2">text2</child2>
    </parent>
</root>
"@

$xmlDocument = [xml]$xml

$rootElement = $xmlDocument.DocumentElement

$resultList = Convert-XmlElementToList -xmlElement $rootElement

$resultList | Format-Table
```

Comment: unfortunately this just lumps the child property values together next to the root property. I need Property:   Value  for every single property and value in the tree. not just the root.